# How to input dynamic data (processName and pid) in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I've been making a task manager and I'm able to display the processes' name, pid, etc. in textview. which could be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSwCx.jpg

I wanted to convert all of that into List view so that there would be no need in typing the pid then pressing the kill button.

```
  public void showProcess(){//display process currently running processes
    Context context = getApplicationContext(); 

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    try{
        if(list != null){
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){

                //lists the application name, process name and corresponding PIDs in TEXTVIEW
                CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(list.get(i).processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                dispProcesses.append(c.toString()+"\n"+list.get(i).processName + "\t" + list.get(i).pid+ "\n\n");

            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the data there could be retrieved and easily be appended in TextView. However, that is not the case when it comes to ListView. Wherein that kind of data should be stored in some array to be able to display all of that data.

MY QUESTION: How to store that kind of dynamic data(processName,PID,appName) into ListView?

I'm already quite familiar in the static data version of ListView. However, my task manager produces dynamic data and i don't have the slightest idea how to input that in a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can add each process (`String`, id, etc) into an object and then add it to an `ArrayList<YourObject>`. Then build a custome adapter (i.e. a custom `BaseAdapter`) and set it your `ListView`.

Each time a new process is created, add it your `ArrayList`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged` to update your `ListView`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup it kind of did. Thanks. Although I still need to further understand Listview.